# Why does the lasso's learning curve suggests that, at low number of samples, there isn't overfiting?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, statistical-learning

I'm using the lasso penalty in a logistic regression model for classification and I ploted a learning curve using logloss as the performance metric.

Here is what I obtained:

[image: Lasso learning curve]

As the plot shows the training error is always decrasing(in average). But,
I was expecting a plot like the one I obtained unsing logistic regression without penalty:

[image: Logisic regression learning curve]

That is, I was expecting that:

> At low number of samples there is overfiting (low train error/high test error)

But found that for the lasso penalty

> At low number of samples both train and test errors are high.

The question is: **Why does the lasso penalty avoids overfitting?**

**How I potted the curves** (pseudocode)

```
for(sampleSize in c(100,200,...,1500))
  repeat 100 times {
    select `sampleSize` random samples from the data
    train a model
    calculate Train Error
    calculate Test Error on the non-selected samples
  }
  calculate mean train error
  calculate mean test error
```

I have gist of the acctual R code I used but I cant post a link because I need at least 10 reputation. So here is an offuscated link.

gist.github.com  argent0  9b2f82b1072253600aa8

Edit: removed extra word

Comment: There *is* overfitting -- whenever the train error is below the test error, the plot is telling you that the error in the in-sample measurement is optimistically biased. What you've observed is that the *extent* of that bias is smaller in the regularized model.

Comment: @user777 you are correct. I'm still surprised by how using regularization changes the shape of the train error curve.

Comment: This shouldn't really be too surprising, though. Think about the purpose of regularization: the motivation is that (especially in small samples) coefficient estimates can be volatile, i.e. erratically estimated to be very large in absolute value

Comment: Also, what kind of lasso model is used to calculate the prediction error? Since lasso has a lambda parameter which lambda are you using? Typically lambda is chosen by cross validation to minimize some kind of predictive error and this process can inherently make lasso look to perform better

Comment: @bdeonovic. Exactly. I'm using cross validation for each trained model to choose lamda. So the lambda varies along the curve. Kind of lasso model? I'm not sure I follow. It is logistic regression with a penalty on the absolute value of the coefficients. Once I obtain a model (with a particular value of lambda choosen by Cross Validation), I compute the probabilities of being positive class for each sample in the training set for the train error and in a test set for the test error.

Comment: @Overfit, how specifically is the lambda chosen? If it is the lambda that minimizes something related to the loss then lasso's performance does not surprise me. Try holding lambda constant and plotting several curves for various lambdas, I imagine the lasso will act more like the other methods in that case.

Comment: @bdeonovic. Where the it says `train a model`, it trains 100 models with differen values of lambda, then it does 10-fold CV to estimate the test error(on each value of lambda) and, finally, it chooses the lambda that has the best estimated test error. I now understand that using CV to estimate the penalty as produced a model with a train error that is a better estimate of the test error, and that is the reason why the train error curve in the first plot follows the test error. For the second plot, as I'm not doing CV,the train error is  much more optimistic for small number of samples. Thanks.